# GetOpenFileName triggers breakpoint

Tags: c++, dialog, breakpoints

I'm trying to call GetOpenFileName like this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

OPENFILENAME ofn;       // common dialog box structure
wchar_t szFile[260];       // buffer for file name
HWND hwnd;              // owner window
HANDLE hf;              // file handle
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
wchar_t title[500];  // to hold title
GetConsoleTitle( title, 500 );
HWND hwndConsole = FindWindow( NULL, title );
ofn.hwndOwner = hwndConsole;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = L"All\0*.*\0Text\0*.TXT\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

// Display the Open dialog box. 

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE) 
    hf = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile, 
                    GENERIC_READ,
                    0,
                    (LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES) NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                    (HANDLE) NULL);
```

The prog stops (message: example.exe has triggered a breakpoint(not one I placed)) at "if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn)==TRUE)"  When I break i get a message that no source is available.
If I do not break and just press continue, the dialog box pops up and works as expected. What am I doing wrong?
I just noticed that it works without problems in release mode...

Comment: You're mixing Unicode and ANSI strings all over the place... I'm surprised this even compiles. Some strings are prefixed with `L`, yet you're explicitly calling the ANSI versions of several Win32 functions. It's 2012: everything has been fully Unicode for a over a decade.

Comment: Is it a breakpoint or a first chance exception?

Comment: The message says "has encountered a breakpoint"

Comment: Ah, I see why it compiles. You're casting away errors rather than fixing them. This (`ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFile;`) is fundamentally broken. The compiler is trying to warn you that you're mismatching string types, but you're just telling it to shut up. That bites you in the butt at runtime.

Comment: Your right! I added the cast in my despair. also the L ;-). The rest of the code is more or less copied from msdn. (eg ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;) Why can't ms post examples that work? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646829%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#open_file

Comment: The MSDN example is fine assuming you're targeting multibyte character set and not unicode.

Comment: Right, the MSDN example is from 20 years ago. It obviously hasn't been updated. Use `wchar_t` instead of `char` (or use the `TCHAR` macro) and prefix *all* string literals with an `L` (or use the `TEXT` macro). Then use the macros to let the compiler automatically call the correct function, or explicitly call the `W` functions (not the `A` ones).

Comment: Did that, same problem. Before you ask: Unicode is "on" in the settings.

Comment: Post the updated code so we're all starting on the same page. Use the "edit" link above the tags. It's very strange that you're not getting a detailed error message at runtime. Are you running this in the debugger?

Comment: `GetOpenFileName` may throw one or more exceptions. They will be handled by whatever threw them, maybe that's where VS chokes. This always annoys the heck out of me when using Windbg or Ollydbg.

Answer (score 1):

One possible issue:
`ofn.nMaxFile` should be the number of characters, not the size in bytes of the buffer. Try this instead:

```
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile) / sizeof(wchar_t);
```

Comment: Did not help. I tried to wrap a try / catch around the whole thing, not even that made me any wiser..